# Node js MongoDB login system database values undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, authentication

I am currently working on a login system with Nodejs, Express & MongoDB. Everything works except the values in the database are coming up as undefined. At the two console.log statements where "database ___" is stated, the result is undefined. Not too sure why, from some testing it seems that the user inputted values work fine so I don't know why it's returning undefined.

```
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  //Get user fields
  const userEmail = req.body.loginEmail;
  const userPass = req.body.loginPassword;
  //Is user in database?
  User.find({ email: userEmail }, (err, user) => {
    console.log("database email: " + user.email)
    if (!err) {
      //Compare password to database password
      bcrypt.compare(userPass, user.password, (err, result) => {
        console.log("database password: " + user.password);
        //If user pass in database, check if verified & redirect to success
        if (userPass === user.password) {
          if (user.isVerified) {
            res.redirect("/success");
          } else {
            res.send(
              "You are not verified. Please check your email to access your account."
            );
          }
        } else {
          res.send("Incorrect password");
        }
      });
    } else {
      res.send(err);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This part **User.find({ email: userEmail }, (err, user) => {** refers to Mongoose library?

Comment: Yes I'm using Mongoose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose will return an array as the second argument to the callback function when you use [find()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.find). If you use [findOne()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.findOne) a single document will be returned instead.